# Deleting a pointer to a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, delete-operator

I have a `const std::vector<double> *vecPtr` inside a class. I want to correctly deallocate memory, so what should my `destructor` look like?

I tried `~ClassA() { delete[] vecPtr; }` , but i get an error

```
*** Error in `./test': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff8c643a98 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Does `delete[]` work only if vector is filled with pointers?

EDIT:

I use `vecPtr` like this: `vecPtr = &vec;`

If i use just `delete` i get `*** Error in ./test': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000008fcb20 ***`

Comment: A pointer to a vector is almost always an error. Try using a vector instead.

Comment: why is that, i want to avoid copying

Comment: You cannot avoid copying by sticking a `*` in front of a class member.

Comment: In fact any pointer used as a class member is almost always an error. One exception to this is when you are handed a pointer by third-party code. In most other cases you should be using a shared_ptr or a unique_ptr or nothing instead of a `*`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on how you created `vecPtr`. If you used `vecPtr = new std::vector<double>`, you should use `delete vecPtr;`

If `vecPtr` is created by `array new`, such as `vecPtr = new std::vector<double>[3];`, you should use `array delete`, `delete[] vecPtr;`

**EDIT**

If you used `vecPtr = &vec;`, and if `vec` is an auto variable, which used automatic memory, or `vec` is a static variable or global variable, which used static memory, you should not delete it, it will be deallocated automatically. Only dynamic memory could be deleted.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the []. It is used to delete arrays.

```
delete vecPtr;
```

You probably should not be using pointers to vector as there is not much reason to.

Comment: Why not...? A vector on dynamic memory makes usually more sense so you don't affect the limited stack.

Answer (score 1):

```
const std::vector<double> *vecPtr
```

vecPtr is a pointer to a a "vector", ie a single object. Don't think of it as an array and use the array delete call (which is there for backwards compatible C arrays anyway), but think of it as what it is - a pointer to an object.

for example, if you have written your own vector class, lets call it vecarray, then you would have:

```
const vecarray *vecPtr.
```

You would obviously delete this using `delete vecPtr`. Vectors, and other stl container classes, are no different.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your edit doesn't really clarify and in fact introduces more problems.  Is `vec` actually an automatic variable and therefor should never be deleted?  We don't know.

To answer your rather vague question though, if you allocate a vector on the free store it should be deleted just with `delete ptr`.  If your `ptr` actually points at an array then you should use array delete with `delete [] ptr`.  This at least is apparently not the case.  If you're just assigning an address of a vector to `ptr` then you should probably never delete it.  Conflating ownership like that causes an orgy of problems.